# mean value theorem to prove: $\ln(x^2 +1)\leqslant x^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to use the mean value theorem to prove: $\ln(x^2 +1)\leqslant x^2$

i am not very familiar with using this to prove things so i am not sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = \ln (x+1)$. On the interval $[0,x]$, one can find some $\xi $ so that

$$ \frac{ f(x) - f(0) }{x-0} = f'(\xi) = \frac{1}{1+\xi} $$

Thus,

$$ \frac{ \ln (x+1) }{x} = \frac{1}{1 + \xi} \leq 1 \implies \ln(x+1) \leq x $$

Now, replacing $x$ with $x^2$ we have

$$ \ln ( x^2 + 1 ) \leq x^2 $$

Comment: Careful: if $g(x)=\ln(x^2+1)$, then $g'(x) = \frac{2x}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: This doesn't matter; proving $\ln(1+x)≤x$ for all non-negative $x$ is equivalent to proving $\ln\left(1+x^2\right)≤x^2$ for all $x$.

Comment: perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$1+x^2 \le 1+x^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^4 +\ldots = e^{x^2} \implies \log(1+x^2)\le x^2$$

Comment: Clever solution, but does not make use of the MVT

Answer (score 0):

Setting $u=x^2$, this amounts to proving that , ig $u\ge 0$, one  has $\;\ln(1+u)\le u$.

Now you can use this corollary of the *Mean value theorem*:

> Let $I$ be an interval of $\mathbf R$, and $a\in I$. Suppose two differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ are defined on $I$ and satisfy
>
> 1. $f(a)\le g(a)$,
> 2. for all $x>a$ in $I$, $\;f'(x)\le g'(x)$.
>
> Then  for all $x\ge a$ in $I$, $\;f(x)\le g(x)$.

Indeed
$$\ln'(1+u)=\frac1{1+u}\le (u)'=1$$
since $u\ge 0$.

*Alternatively*, $\ln(1+u)\le u$ because the function $\ln(1+u)$ is *concave*, and $y=u$ is the equation of the tangent to its representative curve at $u=0$.